# Rails database query - is it possible to give a column an alias?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, alias

I've got to produce a json feed for an old mobile phone app and some of the labels need to be different from my database column names.

I think the most efficient way of doing this would be to do a create an alias at the database level. So I'm doing things like

```
Site.where( mobile_visible: true ).select("non_clashing_id AS clientID")
```

which produces the SQL

```
SELECT non_clashing_id AS clientID FROM `sites` WHERE `sites`.`mobile_visible` = 1 ORDER BY site_name
```

If I run this query in MYSQL workbench it produces a column with the heading `ClientID` as I expect, with the required values.

But if I show the object in a rails view I get `{"clientID":null},{"clientID":null},{"clientID":null}`

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by default, `activerecord` loads column definitions from the database. And, it should load value into existing columns only.

```
Site.columns
```

I guess you could add one more item to that array. Or you could use the normal query without alias column name, then add `alias_attribute` like MurifoX did and overwrite `as_json` method:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :client_id, :non_clashing_id

  def as_json(options={})
    options[:methods] = [:client_id]
    options[:only] = [:client_id]
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This shows how to access the variable

```
sites = Site.where( mobile_visible: true ).select("non_clashing_id AS clientID")
sites.each do |site|
  puts site.clientID
end
```

Comment: This is right, but be aware that none of your other columns are going to be available this way. i.e. using `select()` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` will replace the default `SELECT site.*` value entirely. So you'll want to use something like `"sites.*, sites.non_clashing_id AS clientID"`

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your model in addition to the database alias:

```
class model < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :non_clashing_id, :client_id
  ...
end
```